# How can I create a virtual switch for VMs to use a different VLAN than my host Windows 10 Professional machine?

Tags: networking, hyper-v, vlan, windows-10-pro

My host machine is plugged into a Unifi switch that has access to all my VLANs (configured in pfSense). My host machine is connected to the main/management LAN on `192.168.1.x`.

I am trying to configure Hyper-V such that:

- My host stays on `192.168.1.x`
- Some VMs are connected to a virtual switch that joins VLAN 10
- Some VMs are connected to a virtual switch that joins VLAN 20
- Some VMs are connected to a virtual switch that joins VLAN 30

I figure I have to create 4 virtual switches and specify the VLAN ID in the switch properties.

When I create a new virtual switch, and uncheck the `Allow management operating system to share this network adapter`, it does not let me specify the VLAN ID. If I leave that box checked, then my host machine will also be connected to this switch to get an IP in that VLAN and I don't want that.

**main LAN switch that my host machine will also use**

[image: main LAN switch that my host machine will also use]

**trying to create a virtual switch for VLAN 10 but I can't specify the VLAN ID**

[image: trying to create a virtual switch for VLAN 10 but I can't specify the VLAN ID]

Comment: Have you tried giving the VMs different External Virtual Switches and set to use static IP addresses from the other VLANs?

Comment: Generally, you don't.  You assign the vLan to the vNIC inside the VM, not on the host's virtual switch.